# Animating shorthand CSS properties with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Chapter 3 of *jQuery Novice to Ninja* starts with a section about animating CSS properties, and its first example suggests the following code should expand padding and add a couple of borders to every paragraph in a page:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('p').animate({
    padding: '20px',
    borderBottom: '3px solid #8f8f8f',
    borderRight: '3px solid #bfbfbf'
  }, 2000);
});
```

However, while the code indeed works with the jQuery 1.4 library included in the downloadable examples archive for the book, it only animates padding when used alongside jQuery 1.6, forgetting the shorthand CSS properties for `border-bottom` and `border-right` altogether.

What happened in the transition between 1.4 and 1.6, causing the removal of this functionality? Has it been placed in some plugin? Is it possible to run this code *as it's written* and get back the border animation? If not, how would you animate border properties using jQuery 1.6?

Answer (score 2):

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5001#comment:3

User dmethwin pretty much answers that.

Comment: I missed the answer the first time I looked at that thread.  If you look at comment 3, dmethwin explains exactly why this doesn't work.  Thanks @mystrdat!!

Comment: I should have linked straight to the comment, my bad, I thought I did - will fix.

Comment: However, the comment doesn't explain why the example works with the jQuery 1.4 library included in the downloadable examples archive for the book. Was some basic functionality for shorthand properties included in jQuery 1.4, then removed because it was too complex a task to complete? Have the authors modified something in the jQuery 1.4 version they included with the book examples? ...or what? This part of the answer is still missing.

Comment: Giulio, have you confirmed that it does work in 1.4?  I'm not sure how you'd animate some of the things that dmethwin discusses in his comment linked above.

Comment: @TerryDonaghe almost an year has passed, but I remember using the source code straight from the examples downloadable archive, and it worked. I wouldn't have written it in the question otherwise. While I would say that this particular example works, I don't know about general shorthand properties animation rules in jQuery 1.4 or 1.6. I had hoped someone would chime in and shed some light on the issue, but alas no such luck.

Comment: It may be that 1.4 jQuery was in fact parsing some shorthands for just a single value (let's say width in case of the border) and it was later found that it's not entirely a reasonable behavior. Just a guess.